# What is the relationship between Hadoop's version and Hadoop-common's version?

Tags: maven, hadoop

I am using **Maven** to build a **Hadoop** project, and searching the dependencies in http://search.maven.org/.

The results of **Hadoop-common** only include version **0.2x** and **2.x**, and what about the **version 1.x**?

Here is the [search link](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.apache.hadoop%22%20AND%20a%3A%22hadoop-common%22).

It seems that **Hadoop's version** is not corresponding with its **Hadoop-common's version**.

By the way, [Differences between Hadoop-common, Hadoop-core and Hadoop-client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28856096/differences-between-hadoop-common-hadoop-core-and-hadoop-client)

Then if I choose **Hadoop 1.2.1**, which version should I write for the maven decencies in the **.pom** file ? (Or, Is it must to write a specific version of **Hadoop-Common** and **Hadoop-Client** ?)

Hope for an explanation in detail.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Hadoop version 1.x(Hadoop old API) then you should use corresponding dependencies in your maven project. ie, artifacts with version 1.x. It is available in the Maven central repository.
Accept my answer if you have the solution.