# Maven Dependency Analyze complains about CDH dependencies Hadoop-Client and Hadoop-Common

Tags: maven, hadoop, dependency-management, cloudera-cdh, maven-dependency-plugin

In my hadoop project, I have decided to use only one CDH dependency 'hadoop-client' as suggested by [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28856096/differences-between-hadoop-common-hadoop-core-and-hadoop-client).

This is my dependency in the POM:

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
     <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
     <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>
```

When I run `mvn dependency:analyze` this is what I get:

```
[WARNING] Used undeclared dependencies found:
[WARNING]    org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:jar:2.6.0-cdh5.5.1:compile
[WARNING] Unused declared dependencies found:
[WARNING]    org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:jar:2.6.0-cdh5.5.1:provided
```

Why is not hadoop-common being resolved from hadoop-client. And why does maven think hadoop-client is not being used?

THanks.

Comment: Maybe because it isn't used?

Comment: hadoop-common is used from almost every hadoop-* jars, and client definitely uses classes in common.