# Hadoop File System Shell : bin/hdfs dfs <args>

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

From [File System Shell](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/file_system_shell.html) for **Hadoop 1.2.1**, it says:

The FS shell is invoked by:

```
 bin/hdfs dfs <args>
```

Actually, I cannot find any **hdfs** in **HADOOP_HOME/bin** directory.

So, what does it mean?

By the way, what are the differences with `hadoop fs <args>`?

Comment: Regarding your second question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384479/differnce-between-hadoop-dfs-and-hadoop-fs
Also, which version of hadoop are you using?

Answer (score 0):

`hdfs dfs<args>` is used by Hadoop new API.
`hadoop fs<args>` is used by Hadoop old API.
So change it according to your installed Hadoop version.

Comment: Since you may are familiar with `hadoop`， can u help me solve those questions ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28855518/what-is-the-relationship-between-hadoops-version-and-hadoop-commons-version; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28856096/differences-between-hadoop-common-hadoop-core-and-hadoop-client

Comment: Okay! I'm also a learner in Hadoop. But I can help you from what I've got.